# Copying excell columns from one spreadsheet to another using macros

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if some one could help me with a problem I am having with the following code

```
Sub CopyData()
'
' CopyData Macro
' Copys the raw data to the consolidated report
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+w
'Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range
Dim I As Integer
Dim OldColumn(1 To 7) As String
Dim NewColumn(1 To 7) As String
    OldColumn(1) = "A"
    OldColumn(2) = "O"
    OldColumn(3) = "J"
    OldColumn(4) = "M"
    OldColumn(5) = "N"
    OldColumn(6) = "P"

    NewColumn(1) = "A"
    NewColumn(2) = "B"
    NewColumn(3) = "C"
    NewColumn(4) = "D"
    NewColumn(5) = "E"
    NewColumn(6) = "H"

        For I = 1 To 7
            Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("HalliburtonNAFTA").Worksheets("RawData").Columns(OldColumn(I))
            Set targetColumn = Workbooks("HalliburtonNAFTA").Worksheets("NAFTAReport").Columns(NewColumn(I))
                targetColumn = sourceColumn.Value
                sourceColumn.Copy
                targetColumn.Paste
        Next I

    Application.Goto Reference:="CopyData"
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

I am getting one of two errors when I run this code.

1. I get a type mismatch on the set sourceColumn line because I am copying data over that has formulas in the cells rather than the value of the cell
2. On the tagetColumn.Paste line I get an object required, so I am not sure whats going on there.

If anyone could help out that would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about with get rid of the sourceColumn and targetColumn variable all together - we don't really need them:

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim I As Integer
Dim OldColumn(1 To 7) As String
Dim NewColumn(1 To 7) As String
    OldColumn(1) = "A"
    OldColumn(2) = "O"
    OldColumn(3) = "J"
    OldColumn(4) = "M"
    OldColumn(5) = "N"
    OldColumn(6) = "P"

    NewColumn(1) = "A"
    NewColumn(2) = "B"
    NewColumn(3) = "C"
    NewColumn(4) = "D"
    NewColumn(5) = "E"
    NewColumn(6) = "H"

        For I = 1 To 6
            Worksheets("NAFTAReport").Range(NewColumn(I) & "5:" & NewColumn(I) & Rows.Count).Value = Worksheets("RawData").Range(OldColumn(I) & ":" & OldColumn(I)).Value
        Next I

    Application.Goto Reference:="CopyData"
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: awesome! Also when copying over to the new columns, how do I set the beginning cell. (EX) rather than the data being copied over starting at row/col A1, I want it to start row/col A5

Comment: Now when I copy over the cells, I get a type mismatch error because it's coping over the formula rather than a value. How do I get it so the value come over and not the formula?

Comment: I've updated the answer - it should now copy values instead of formulas, and it starts at row 5.

Comment: So I ran that code, and it's only pasting to the 5th row and nothing below that? How do I make it so it continues copying and pasting data after that?